# JS Why are these booleans returning wrong values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, boolean

For some reason, the boolean `meaningfulIndexes.indexOf(index) != -1` returns false 100% of the time, and I suspect that the `arrayFindNext` does also. Why could this be? `finalProcessing` is an array that has a fixed size of 64, and `bars` has a length of 128.

```
meaningfulIndexes = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
    meaningfulIndexes.push((bars.length / 64) + i * (bars.length / 64))
}

bars.forEach((currentValue, index, array) => {

    if (index == 0) {

            array[index].desiredHeight = finalProcessing[0] * canvas.height / 3 + 1;
    }

    if (meaningfulIndexes.indexOf(index) != -1) {

            array[index].desiredHeight = finalProcessing[meaningfulIndexes.indexOf(index)] * canvas.height / 3 + 1;

    }
    else {

            array[index].desiredHeight = (((array[index - 1].desiredHeight - 1) * 3 / canvas.height + finalProcessing[meaningfulIndexes.findIndex(arrayFindNext(index))]) / 2) * canvas.height / 3 + 1;
    }
})

function arrayFindNext(value) {
    return value > i;
}
```

Comment: First, I'd remove the function declarations from the body of the loop and begin using `Array` looping methods, like `.forEach()` to greatly simplify your code and eliminate all the looping indexes, which are surely contributing to the problem. Then, I'd use `.indexOf`, rather than reinventing the wheel to find out if your array contains something.

Comment: I removed the `arrayContains` function and replaced it with `meaningfulIndexes.indexOf(i) != -1`, but the problem still persists. And the code somehow works if I set the value manually to true.

Comment: Did you also stop using loops with counter indexes and switch to using `.forEach()` to loop over your arrays? Did you move `arrayFindNext` function to be outside of the loop?

Comment: I think I can't stop using the for loops, because I need the index for other calculations. And I moved the `arrayFindNext` outside.

Comment: Yes you can. [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) can provide you with an index via the callback function arguments that you pass to it. It makes the code SO much simpler and easier to debug.

Comment: I moved the code to a `.forEach()` loop, but the problem didn't solve. The edited code is at the top.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain what it is you are actually trying to do. Now, that the code is simplified, it's clearer that your logic is flawed. `if (meaningfulIndexes.indexOf(index) != -1)` translates to `if meaningfullIndexes.indexOf(0) != -1)` on the first iteration and then increases from there, so it would always be true that the value doesn't equal  `-1`, which means that you would never fall into the `else` branch.

Comment: I found that the logic is flawed in the last `else` branch. The code should get the average of the last object's `.desiredHeight` before any calculations and the next object in the `finalProcessing` array with the index of the `meaningfulIndexes` array. I also changed the `if` statement's requirement to `index != 0 && index % (array.length / 64) == 0`.